# Defined Global variable, however unable to use it. Please suggest

Tags: java, junit

I am newbie to Java and facing below issue. I have following code:

```
public class ReadExcel {    
Config conf = new Config();
String filePath = conf.getInputfilePath();

@Test
public void readFullXL() {      
try {
FileInputStream FSRead = new FileInputStream(filePath);
```

I have declared this variable ‘filePath’ outside function because; I want to use it as global variable. 
However, inside readFullXL(), I am not able to get value for variable ‘filePath’ and getting null pointer exception.

Can somebody suggest? How I can declare global variable in Junit file.

Comment: Then you get a value though this value is `null`. This is a valid behavior if `conf.getInputfilePath()` returned `null`.

Comment: Holger, I didn't understand. Why this is valid behaviour?

Comment: If `filePath` is `null` you will get a NullPointerException. Point. As already said you have to check whether the result of `conf.getInputfilePath()` is `null` and if so why it is `null`. Since we do not know anything about your Config class we can not even guess.

Comment: I am putting more details below, can you please check and look into it?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Of course first you gotta check that your `getInputfilePath()` method does not return null.

**Further**: I suggest you go ahead and read some informations on UnitTesting ([JUnit - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html)).

If it's just one test you could just instantiate your needed classes within that test.

```
@Test
public void readFullXL() {      
    Config conf = new Config();
    FileInputStream FSRead = new FileInputStream(conf.getInputfilePath());
    //...

}
```

---

If you have multiple tests relying on the same fixture you can go ahead and implement a setup method using the `@Before` annotation. The setup method will then be called before every test (`@Test` annotation) method.

```
class ReadExcel {    
Config conf; 

@Before
public void setUp() {
    conf = new Config();
}

@Test
public void readFullXL() {      
    //...
    FileInputStream FSRead = new FileInputStream(conf.getInputfilePath());
    // Run your test

}
}
```

Comment: Did you check (debug) the return value of conf.getInputfilePath()?

Comment: in debug mode it returns Null

Comment: I am putting more details below, can you please check and look into it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response and time. 
I got it working by creating interface between config and ReadExcel file.
Also removed Junit test annotation from config file that was not required.

Thanks,
Ashvini